# Hyperbolic isometries and finite order elements

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm reading a paper and I'm uncertain about one of its claims. I was wondering if someone could clarify. Namely, it states that for a discrete subgroup of $\text{Isom } H^n$, the finite order elements are the elliptic isometries. My question is why can we not have any finite order loxodromic or parabolic isometries also be elements in this subgroup?

**EDIT:** For reference I am reading "Geometrical Finiteness for Hyperbolic Groups"

Comment: They can be elementa of a discrete subgroup. They will not be **finite order** elements, however.

Comment: @sandwich can you elaborate why loxodromic and parabolic isometries cannot be of finite order.

Comment: I assume that loxodromic refers to an isometry of the hyperbolic n-space which has an invariant geodesic and acts on it as a nontrivial translation, say, by $t$. What do you think will the the translation parameter for the $k$th power of such an isometry? Now, do the same for a parabolic isometry.